# Can't seem to get printing script to function remotely

Tags: batch-file, printing, cmd

I came across a printer install script that is copied directly from Google. It installs the print driver every single time you install a new printer, which takes forever, and you have to be on the physical PC to use it.

I've tried something like the below, but get an error that my arguments are invalid.

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /c\\PCName /m "HP Universal Printing PCL 6" /f "\\server\path\path\path\hpcu186u.inf"
```

I've also tried it with `/K, /v, and /h` in there to no avail. I can get it to run if I take out the `/c` and run it on the target PC, but even then I get an error about UNC paths not being supported.

I've also tried using *prndrvr.vbs* similarly but get an `error 87` with that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

### Partial answer

The fun with UNC parts should be easy:

Use `pushd \\server\path` to short time map a network drive to use it as a physical one. More info with `pushd /?`. To unmap the drive use `popd`.

However I am not sure in how far your script "did not work" with using the /c option as in your question. It might already have been sufficient to solve the UNC-path problem.